# The Virasoro-Bott group and the KdV equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lie-groups, physics, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

The Euler Arnold equation expresses equations (usually from mathematical physics) as geodesic equations on a Lie group. For the famous $KdV$ equations these equations are given on the Virasoro-Bott group, a central extension of the group of diffeomorphisms of the circle. Since then other equations of fluid mechanics have been constructed on this group (with a different metric).

it is easy to understand, intuitively, why an equation of fluid dynamics would be a geodesic equation on a group of diffeomorphisms, but I don't see where the central extension comes in. How was this discovered? What was the motivation for using the central extension of such a lie group to describe these equations?